# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I’ve been at this for a very, very long time(3 weeks) in Eclipse.  Using the ‘Getting Started’ guide for google maps android api v2 I keep running into this issue.   I’ve tried all the various ways of making this work from posts on SO in addition to following various tutorials online & on youtube and I still can’t get it to function.  I’ve used Activity, FragmentActivity, ,  , adding name to fragment and there’s still an error inflating the class fragment.

Main error(topmost error in LogCat)

```
03-12 11:50:04.793: E/AndroidRuntime(9002): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.map2/com.example.map2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
```

MainActivty.java (I’ve tried both Activity & FragmentActivity)

```
package com.example.map2;

import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Activity_main.xml (I’ve used both MapFragment & SupportMapFragment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.example.map2.MainActivity"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Map2Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.map2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.map2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
    Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="#" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.map2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

screenshots of library settings, etc:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @FCo AFAIK that is not the problem its a child of application tag and that is right

Comment: @Raghunandan it is advised that you place it before the `</application>` closing tag at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2 .  
It has been a problem for other people before.

Comment: @FCo no it does not say so. it says before closing tag meaning child of application tag

Comment: @Raghunandan "In AndroidManifest.xml, add the following element as a child of the <application> element, by inserting it just before the closing tag </application>:" - step 1 of adding API key to your application.  Personally caused a problem for me when I didn't have it in the right spot before.

Comment: @FCo that means to say as a child of application tag. try it yourself there should not be a problem

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
android:minSdkVersion="13"
```

So you need to use `MapFragment` and extend `Activity`.

Change this

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

to

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

And change this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

ALso misisng a metag as a child of application tag

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: So I made your changes and moved the meta data before the </application> like others stated.  I get the 'Unable to execute dex: java heap space' prompt.(I've done all of the suggestions on increasing maxpermsize, xms, etc in eclipse.ini file).  My log cat usually lists errors at this point, but right now its not showing anything.

Comment: @KFP this has nothing to do with your code. Also as a child of </application> tag means before the tag closes. what you had was right. Nothing wrong in having at the start. Its just before close of the tag. If you have it at the start also its a child of application tag. As far as the problem you say in the comment has nothing to do with the code

Comment: Also:I can't step through or even terminate a program once its ran.  The eclipse I'm using(22.3.0) has all of those commands greyed out.  My green arrow always shows that the app is still running.  I've posted this issue on SO as well, but as of now no solution.  Yet another bug i guess.

Comment: @KFP you need to test it on a real device. You can't create avd was the bug filed will fixed in next uild

Comment: I'm am using a real device.  If I uncheck Android Private libraries in Java Build path(to resolve java heap space error) it gets past that and attempt to run on device but fails and I get "error inflating class fragment.

Comment: @KFP  those are not be unchecked. try increase the heap space for eclipse and run the app again

Comment: I've increased those values to 8512!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49678/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-kfp)

Answer (score 0):

This: 
`<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="#" />`
should be just before this: `</application>`
This may not fix your problem but it could cause another one later.

Also, if that's your entire manifest file, then you're missing another `<meta-data>`:
`<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Answer (score 0):

I follow the Google Maps Android API V2 tutorial and I have the same code like you. I got this problems and I have solved it.
If you want to create the Google Map in android api < 11, you should keep your activity and your layout. You must add the add
on your android Android Manifest file.

**< meta-data 

            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"

            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />**

Here is my Android Manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demogooglemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.demogooglemap.permision.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.demogooglemap.permision.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCpDUn3K-IJJxqTmR4qIsNHGgNdqF7YmV0" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope someone will find it useful.
I encountered the same issue and tried a number of fixes , but nothing worked.I solved it as following.
1) I am using Android 2.1.2.
2) I created fragment using the automatic fragment creation method as shown in
[this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7UNL.jpg).
3) Every time I run the program i get the same error.

->**Solution**

- I created the java class and XML fie for my fragment separately.as
  following. [Java Class Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcfxi.jpg).

  Similarly I created a new layout file for the fragment.

And did the following in my newly created java class.

```
package com.example.shaoorjan.fragmentxml;

  import android.app.Fragment;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;


   public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank,container,false);
}
 }
```

It worked all right.